# Unhandled Promise rejection: ; Zone: angular ; Task:

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, angular

meteor and when setting up a (click) attribute I get the following error.

[image: error]

My code is

```
import { Component, NgZone, AfterContentInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { NgIf, NgFor } from 'angular2/common';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { RouterLink, RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
import { CapitalizePipe } from '../../../../lib/pipes/capitalize.ts';
import { Groups } from '../../../../collections/groups.ts';
import { MeteorComponent } from 'angular2-meteor/meteor_component';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

@Component({
  selector: 'manage-players',
  templateUrl: '/client/components/loggedIn/players/manage-players.html',
  directives: [ RouterLink, NgIf, NgFor ],
  pipes: [CapitalizePipe]
})

export class ManagePlayers extends MeteorComponent {
  importPlayers: Object;
  groups: Mongo.Cursor;
  pendingImport_placementGroups: Array;
  pendingImport_players: Array;

  constructor( zone:NgZone ){
    super();
    var that = this;
    this.subscribe('groups', () => {
      this.groups = Groups.find();
    },true);
  }

  createImportGroups() {
    console.log('Do something!');
  }
```

And the triggering html is:

```
<a href="#!" class="create-import-groups btn-flat" (click)="createImportGroups()" >Create Groups</a>
```

Whenever I click the above link I get the above errors.
Sorry if I formatted my question incorrectly or missed any information, I'm still relatively new to asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have found the answer to my own question, although I'm not experienced or knowledgeable enough with Angular2 or even javascript to understand why.

The solution to my problem was the fact that I was using an anchor tag with the click event and I believe it's because angular has it's own way to handle anchor tags and the (click) attribute was attempting to interfere with that functionality.

Original:

```
  <a href="#!" class="create-import-groups btn-flat" (click)="createImportGroups()" >Create Groups</a>
```

Replaced by:

```
 <button class="create-import-groups btn-flat" (click)="createImportGroups()" >Create Groups</button>
```

I'd still like to know more about this topic if available.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use MD in comments.. but here is a try, you'll have to unravel it as best you can.

Your function needs to accept the event and then call stopPropagation() on the event

in your html
```
(click)="createInportGroups($event)"
```

in your class
```
createImportGroups(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // your other code here
}
```